# How can I append the items of two different lists to seperate columns in an output file, using python?

Tags: python-3.x

Lets say,

```
list1 = [1,2]    
list2 = [3,4]
```

how can I create an output file where the data looks like,

```
1 3    
2 4
```

I have the following code:

```
for item in xcoords:  
    print (item)                  
    out = open("file.txt", "a")  
    out.write("%s \n" %(item))  
    out.close()  

for item in ycoords:  
    print (item)  
    out = open("file.txt", "a")  
    out.write("%s \n" %(item))  
    out.close()
```

However, it prints:

```
1  
2  
3  
4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *zip()* method to iterate 2 objects at the same time:

```
out = open("file.txt", "a")
for item in zip(list1, list2):
    print (item[0] + " " + item[1]+ "\n")
    out.write("%s %s \n" % (item[0], item[1]))
out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `zip` to iterate over both lists simultaneously.

```
with open("file.txt", "a") as file:
    for x, y in zip(list1, list2):
        print x, y
        file.write("{} {}".format(x,y))
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are of the same length, you can use `zip()` function.

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [2,3,4]
out = open("file.txt", "a")  

for x,y in zip(list1,list2):
    out.write("%s \n" %(item))  
out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list are the same length then you can use zip.

```
out = open ("file.txt","a")
for x,y in zip(list1,list2):
  out.write("%s %s\n" % (x,y))
out.close()
```